# how to insert a variable into an xml file before using wget

Tags: unix

I have the following looop

```
for i in $(cat numbers.txt);
do echo $i;
wget -a output.txt --no-check-certificate http://localhost:9001 --post-file=netev.xml;
done
```

but the netev.xml has a fieled which is defined by the variable $1, this $1 needs to corrospond to value of i for that iteration......

how can i make this work?

thanks

Comment: show the structure of netev.xml

Comment: @ghostdog74 I understood the question as meaning that it was necessary to create the proper netev.xml before calling `wget`, not to obtain a value from the file. If this is the intended meaning, the structure of the file is not very important after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template netev.xml where the value is replaced by a token that is unlikely to occur naturally in the file (say, IVALUE) and use `sed` to substitute $1 to IVALUE in the template.

```
$ cat > template
toto = IVALUE
titi
$ sed s/IVALUE/foo/ < template 
toto = foo
titi
```

Comment: thanks I changed the $1 in the xml file to IValue and did the following 
seems to work
thanks
==================================================================
for i in $(cat numbers.txt);
do echo $i;
sed 's/IValue/'$1'g' netev.xml > netevMOD.xml;
wget -a output.txt --no-check-certificate http://localhost:9001 --post-file=netevMOD.xml;
done
==============================================================